# How to insert multiple documents into sub document at once in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a collection which has a sub-document of array like this below:

```
const ChapterSchema = new Schema({
    intro: { type: String },
    topics: { type: [TopicSchema] }
},
```

I want to add multiple topics in `topics` sub-document of Chapter. I can insert a single topic by this code below:

```
ChapterSchema.update(
  {_id: /* doc id */ },
  {$push: {'topics.$': { /* single topic object */ }},
  callback
)
```

But, I want to insert a topic array to the above sub-documents. How could I able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$push` offers a special syntax with [$each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#append-multiple-values-to-an-array):

```
ChapterSchema.update(
    { _id: /* doc id */ },
    { $push: {'topics': { $each: /* array of topics */ }},
    callback
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps me a lot :D